# How i get domain max value with some extra addtion to larget value used in chart on y axis overall?

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-embed, vega-lite-api

I am trying to create a layered chart in vega lite and i am trying to get the max value from overall data that are used on y axis dynamic like that it must be independent on the field (must dynamic any field xyz used on y axis it does not make any issue)

i want like above because symbol diamond cut look bad for analysis in my specs
[Editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgRghgxg1g5gJwPYFcB2ATEAuUBTADwAcEcQAhaeZdDAYQjQDcIBnOpAGyVIF8AaEFCRoAZgEs4OUBALjW0kJwhg8nAGIiALgGUtAT055FhEmQCCc1gBkVazWl0GjIASC3itRh08PHcIKak2CCW8gAqnt7aen6ubqLaJsTBID7h+kTGbkZweJiKyqqcHNzB+Clk1nh5mLbFpTyugkX2MeIAXv4VZiHVtRj1bY46ndktdhoxzt2BlX01+YOTPrEuOZPW4gC2nsm9IP1LQ5ycO3sbxQDyoqKseFr7qUd1kzd3D81Kb0TQnvpPKqLV7XIjiKD-L7KfSoR4BMBILRaJDbRSMKAACyaIV2GAw60EyKIaLQmOxIFx+Oybh44nycJ6z2BGCuCDpji+rH02wRnCuvwhBkBCwGOm5vP54MhvDcHi8s0SIxmwpAkXlq2VblYKDAcuiSriASCZB0Or1eA1cRlbgwEC0EEULE4KDwCmwAG1QAAFZAYFBQLRoCDbfwgADiCAgRAxABE7Q7BABRYh4AN4eioDnYABMAAYAJwAdkEOggRg46Dh2YAHNn84JzEw4BWswBGfMANlzAm9vv9geDoYAshgCDBxEY0CAkym0xnKzhsx387mS2W8C24a3czuG03N4vlx2eyAfUg-QGgyGyKwAI6cEhIacgZNZOcH7Ct7MAZlXIFL5aZlu2YAKx-o2zZAYu1Y7ieZ4XgO14hIwaCIna4hoFIM5vlo6YftuMFroBC45jB4H7lBpGwQAum4vyRtsbqeiAV6hoQWgMbIz7GjisgAAQAFR8a2AB0IHNKArFkNsXGCDxIC2vaAAUADkrCoAgUB4AA+rmKkAJTurm1EiUOsgAGplhJLGDmQACaYSsGqRgABrPk6Lo4AAtAALN2-CSbZIpLKy7KPIIHmhkS1lScFIJqJQ9xnGgxgRWWnk4uIeIEoFSGHMyJyNKQaXOqGADEO6VbmMVBflAwnKsYzuel-itt+J6xXVxyTGcuzhSAkU4P5uWhi8yzXLc9z9YN2DDTZeVjSckqCgCJUZa2HW1WNYo8lwy2QmtrWbXl6jiAgrBaNt4pcM1pU3reKAQAg4wjSaqYiIMzI7byt0Ze4bKMHAOXzaG4QYmdn2itdnC-aGGDiMGH01XlLmOSc5iYS4h04Cux2hnZABKgN4DJBCwzgaAoKceP2UTmEkxh5PYJT1MBSD9lo5MGNA6lA0tUNNMhKaYBqhOG5cE02MhDwxPI6DUQWtoRVM+AyiwHLZDOYrIxNVLrbHmznVa+YZxwFOUtCPSeB8IbtVa+E7Eq6w66sHxikOoLqoKxjZLFXzd2ZdlL3syEWuJWoGG8zN7hIMSntazGZNS3NnXC+aPgq7yWDxwrWx9UzKd2wr7xTQXntpwrKsa0LZoK41XRM-rntmQgMD8n8Qp657WwpQA6llWgYkz2aew5VhayrwiVtp7vVyAqPj5XFvwf2Umewv8gnHnezJ6PnPFNv0387Ne9WCcowN3r7W2yj+9qBfUfH21693yUEt+9HYBqzAc9j5vkzKwtl-Kgc8N5OXBDAB+w9C55T-uA2AUC9YwNGgVSYiD-brWvq9Pokcrq7U4OgmauMb740clrQBGDQzAPVi-Re8oKGf2-r-Mhdd2iX0oTgJuJCyBgK1vXR+AcuHYJAHAmMKIICMylkZfguYRIdlotwnBKUGHHwGuILgnxy7vTqJHFRAcQDPWzoo08SAMJaG5ljDhJ9jFgwhj3cWZQVaIDwACT2XpTGOAAJJoBSggPRf0mDqKMI8LRwhMDuLMd43x-jQyGLnrYhAGAIleJ8dbGJZBnGuOMckrQVwUC4T8e-FWgSNEhOMTobRSSPG5PyWkopFs4nx3BoknJeSCnpJCJkueLdIEYijAIv6d5HrPW6U9Xp-TCHH1-MgjmVh3EXXUebKxMylF4D0MgGAG4owqxoAUbukd1lIE2XGVgQ8pGthkQo4R9jw7JQGaGO5XkERIhRHPexhzNn9wwIPRu+yUoOzQKwRZvzjGnXOloVpAoDpWI2uUyp7yOJHK2cSBpmYjHCIqWEwYBzEXHLYGcqx7oLnGVCR9G5bAI4pRVo855yJUSkp0SlD5eAvk-K7nCrF9iAVApECCjFlTIUd1WjCppdicUbORTstF8TmnYqZbivAJyCUzSJZc0ViTyVJUjtSyOTzER0plWK+VErWXKqfuquVeBuXAvZcIygsBEBoo6SAMq6g3XutAY5CMWV24rT5SHERXq2QsihZ3ZZtD5DeozI4i2ZUMDfnjfG5hVgo3OrjQmjNhqWnVN9dCmasLhFgPmR4Xlu9QXaAyFkFWDAzhgDZPE1hBpLHR1QggGSMMc7qm0L3PAkgMRH30a29tc8K5dqbfcsgQ6rLl1rmOrQPa+0Dr+lOjtxjX6Wmbaoldc913dt7XAftKtt2exYXOtYE6QjHrXXQ-U8792Hotle65qDigbovSxHgw7Pb2uoE6xgLB2D1KsS691HreDUUJJXAIZZJBTiNPML28oTawa+OiLE5Q5gHGNqSdDXxIBaqpfBrDCtbnarcMIRxRHUh8KVkUm0ZMqOawVonL4ipdBNUY6HRt7GG45HOAyTD1Hc78a+EgSanxOOIaMCXTRghtS6ig4yE0s6CQgHk+aZWknhai0Ao4rUKntY8dmPJUdt6oGykdpJ+2jsZQRTCVAO0OBmL5GEPDTCigGMyCsIoRAWUcAcRdIIXz0bsRKZCGA1NdGgvBtzUKSTEWYuhqyd8YoFjjMIbAejTG4wUtqE02F+er9laXGGEZlUmW0FNRK5wQ+5XX61bokgIFJa4MFaLU1lrXwPAII421lhPXeOQflHVm9OWNNFPi6e3TTRZTcagZN0b-CusQMoAUEI7F6TPlaJwL0EA8QYSkLNIbRg7IC0EBINQWAQgr0vLZOTDmXABAwOIxmAR6LBjIHWlApz4hyZ4AJi7nArsgD87KTIoZUK7CDB2twGJ71VjAhMfQ1snP4FJOeA7igKOhYUnaFAqIQivlTLhecHIWjMkKAAibBXFpU70xMV9bD0sHFp4znWg3cs1ZE5J1naheoXAZ2oGTAn5K875OJspnPYsAh5y+oXYI-VamhtLlUeCJQK+lHJ6G82ae4K+trqrWv8HMvy4JsgrTamFPp2p6GlbmepDBRdNXN1bNqYe7MSM9NUdm+u9UqJdS9MKPcFBkAXwZdefkD54N-mECBZAMF038k4GRet8FlXknk+JaFVCLm2WVRwKyzzHPDRqc+8DWfOnM3BdTHZ-b2Z-9ijmer7VjP9WRONea8C1vcyOvAtmwNuvIQ4GRAH8t4b3eIiV1m-Q0vSepsOKr8Hs9vWy-D7m1VhIdIgdkCJ++KC931yKC6MgHAogyz3C1P9imVNOCEnB2QB6jA5ToSYNSQQMlW6KAkKcMgHFGCsHok23OwnCMCuwCzwEEFjmz0k0dwhRzSSy+CIGqRJCL0kxyTS1YxAJVByX9yt0X1OX6V-wBjzzkxX3kh6R0D6SyHMy1DIIQ3sVNU5AVUYJ53FSRUYNlCQC4A8GJGwHALvyrRCDuUQKemDCYmES+1OWqjkzUGJxMHRzczgCYhADJgg3cHvxCCQLMXiCuUCAUMxwCGxww0Unxx31nBJwPHJwGEpxL0oxpzlzfmt22yW1l3qhWCZ2LzUBb3sLcOKH50l222F1VwcKCOq3Tx8O6lBClCFCV3wXCLL2dz5A1xiKN15B1wSL1yhmN0Nxt2NwVUTwQ0xQ+gt3aSi1yN5DtxVCKLqH13wV+zd0PwCE9zyG9xMwFT91STwL4CD3NDIDDy-y32B13wsP3waMe1AGexkgwjMk8zL1Ji+GPyfGwDP04Avz+wQDhBZlv3UMEJAEf0cE8BfzfwpDGUUHw0pUH3-HhUjlIypU3x-xCD-0BUALJxAG-1AJjzjygL9S03aLMRV0a20OgzzzQOqQwPuJhl+KxRwM6OKzkyoMuIoIRM5DoIOCRImQ31IIblYL7gHiHi1GYLxKqOuONXYKJM4O4PEF4P4J2IeTI0EHe0Ym906kkIxFbGfCSjkKNH0MwmUNUIENDC0I5BlF0Jcwx3c0MNLxMIJ1CAogXCsKWBsLy1n3oIcLhM5xcIiPihrzK2q28ISIcP8M8PFw+BF1VN8KFwl2NPiNFxCOSOSy5DiIQNcKWG+j2ntM5AN2xN1xSkSKb3KK4BNxVKw1lRKID3wNtw0IKwSUhldOhnqNYHd0UGaP8GcwQxjJhOiTox6JD36ICEB2BwgksLUyv2ZhvwFIf0egOPtA8Ff3qI-x-nzKwMeM9wAKeiALeJAPTE+IgJAG+MhCs1DPgOz0BKzBkBBIK3QLzwhJVAzI6KzOtwIN2PhkRgKCxMRLGUoIxN41oO9IyNxO+XxLk0JMPNnNlQRRNXJMJC4M4B4J7IrKEPpJAEZPEIDVZOzA5NkIDHkNcwOz5JADUIMF2KFJCXA3A0EGenUk4DrICETMaNACMLIAwgwDwCyEwA7KXNDGQtQqWE21dyeNYESDbW92-wKUUEZM+1jx+xFIijpAAHcBiHiCsf1HVaBis3A6KiSQhCwdxrIxTFCsdS9o5TZ+0IwIBktZjZBI8Ahts3QVj7hINYA5Lz9ezeiQhMDLtzc+xbtrx1iAdBikKjFaTJ0UQMJp1Yd4cTKqV39TiAh+y4s-wgLQx2yPYGTRCmSPQJCqKCVOTvzuTfzeSnMVCALCRWzlBcJ7zjKQgzFrYnQdDBBOLTzL0RBshaIgA)